# LSTM: Best way to handle categories, in practice

Tags: neural-networks, categorical-data, lstm, categorical-encoding

There is an issue emerging in the practical use of Long-Short-Term-Memory (LSTM) Deep Neural Nets (DNN) with my use case.

In typical machine learning scenarios one encounters in benchmark datasets, or in image analysis, there is full availability of categorical instances during training, and no previously unseen categories at test time or run time.

That is to say, specifically, if there is a categorical column known as `Fruits` containing `{ 'apples', 'oranges'}` in the currently available training set, then it is perfectly ordinary, during live operation, to encounter a novel type of `Fruit` such as `Durian` for which no training data existed.

```
training_fruits = set(training_data['Fruits'])
print(training_fruits)

 {'apples', 'oranges'}

# Some time passes ...

runtime_fruits = set(runtime_data['Fruits'])
print(runtime_fruits)

 {'pears', 'oranges', 'durians'}
```

A simple example of this use case might be a category of good where new products are released in the market every few months.

---

In normal "machine learning", I can handle this in several ways.  But the first step in any of these ways is to use a hashing algorithm to hash categorical values into some int32.  This means that novel categorical values are encodable in a regularized fashion even when they have never been seen by the model or production infrastructure before.

And, in my particular domain, results are perfectly satisfactory if a novel category is encountered...and substantially worse in general if categories are eliminated entirely.  In short, a problem similar to the background class problem emerges: the features are insufficiently complex to describe the variety of models needed. There is a one-to-many relationship between input parameters and predictions, so the model chooses one particular function to model, and stays there.

---

However, it seems like this "hashing trick" will not work **at all** for LSTM DNN.

Further, in my particular use case, and the example above, there does not seem to be enough "support" in the categorical strings themselves to compute an embedding.

Short of dropping the categorical information, or ruling Deep Learning out entirely, what is the best practice for handling this scenario, and encoding the categories for use by the LSTM?

Comment: Why do you think that an LSTM won't be able to use the hashing trick?

Comment: @Sycorax because a novel hash is an arbitrarily huge number that now has to be parsed by continuous functions.  This is, in my estimation, leveraging most of the DNN's extrapolation power and learned-concept complexity at data ingress.   It is also completely probabilistic whether the DNN can handle this hash or that hash without accessing a wild part of the prediction space https://gizmodo.com/this-simple-sticker-can-trick-neural-networks-into-thin-1821735479

Comment: @Sycorax so the model will be unnecessarily bad/underperform relative to its classical counterpart that can set up discrete logic to handle unknown categories.  The LSTM/DNN has only so many parameters, and it is inefficient at learning discrete logic on a per-parameter basis.   Ergo, a discrete logical relation is difficult to learn via the optimization algorithms (it is a low probability result; memorizing the actual categories is a high probability result...which means that an unknown huge hash becomes a singular value -- an `inf` -- bouncing through the net when submitted to most nets)

Comment: @Sycorax the gizmodo article is a bad example, in that single pixels with extreme values, or multiple pixels with subtle changes that access a poorly generalized region (i.e., an area with memorized/embedded training data) of the net can also produce wild output.   And the novel hashes will have this exact effect with some likelihood.

Comment: @Chris I can't see how would LSTM differ from other neural networks in here? Hashing trick is commonly used in natural language processing problems, that commonly use LSTM's *together* with it and this stuff works just fine.

Comment: @Tim Ok, I'll give it a shot and see what happens...

Comment: @Tim maybe my understanding is too theoretical right now, ha ha

Comment: If the main objection is that there are too many hash buckets, that seems easy enough to fix: just specify a smaller number of buckets. If that's no good, then you might need to work harder to generalize information about the products. For instance, the 3-grams of the new prouct "Nvidia RTX 3090 Ti" largely overlap with "Nvidia RTX 2090," so the newer product is similar to the older product in that sense.